# Is it possible to eneble admob ads after certain downloads only?

Tags: android, ads, admob, unityads

I am developing an Android app in which I would be adding admob ads. I want to first make a good userbase so is it possible to enable advertising manually after my app has reached certain downloads? I don't want to show ads until some amount of download occurs?

If there are other more convenient advertising platforms then do suggest them also.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question.

But yes in admobs dashboard you can turn on ads and turn them off. So put the code into the game and just turn ads off in the dashboard.

Then when you hit x number of downloads turn them on in the dashboard.

Comment: I dident found it. Please check

Comment: You should be able to turn off ads for a specific app under the app settings. Alternatively you could turn off all ad networks.